# How i can define custom controller in my controller in sap ui?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, controller, sapui5

So we determine what is in the sap core:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/ui/core/routing/History",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
], function (Controller,History,JSONModel)
```

My sap app id: `"sap.ui.test`".

So I want to connect the controller to one that already exists:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/ui/core/routing/History",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
    "sap/ui/test/webapp/controller/TopMenu"
], function (Controller,History,JSONModel,TopMenu)
```

And I get an error:
`Error: failed to load 'sap/ui/test/webapp/controller/TopMenu.js`.
Although the road looks like right. Project structure attached in the screenshot.

I can not understand whether it is possible to identify the controller in such a way?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use

```js
sap.ui.define([
   "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
   "sap/ui/core/routing/History",
   "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
   "sap/ui/test/controller/TopMenu.controller"
], function (Controller,History,JSONModel,TopMenu)
```

That's because of the old controller naming convention: Your controllers have to be named `ABC.controller.js`.
The `sap.ui.define` function searches for files and is not aware of this convention. It does not know that you would like to load a controller this time.

Comment: Thank's, it work! And how can I use the methods of the class `TopMenu`  in another controller? At the moment I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: TopMenu.setActiveItem is not a function`. I'm trying to do so:
   `onAfterRendering: function(){
   TopMenu.setActiveItem('materData');
  },`

Comment: What you are importing is the class TopMenu. To use its instance methods you would have to instantiate it or you could use it as base class.

Answer (score 0):

try

`sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/ui/core/routing/History",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
    "sap/ui/test/controller/TopMenu"
], function (Controller,History,JSONModel,TopMenu)`

You do not need to tell your app the exact path, you did this already within you Index.html

(something like  `data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"sap.ui.test": "sap/ui/test/webapp"}'>`)

Comment: It's not work, error: `Error: failed to load 'sap/ui/test/controller/TopMenu.js' from ./controller/TopMenu.js: 404 - Not Found`